# Problem with very long latex table

Tags: tables, longtable, tabularx, tabulary

I have a small problem with my thesis. I was adding very long table suitable to 2 pages, but my texmaker editor shows me pdf file on just one page and the table is not completed. NExt issue is, that the last column is too long for a one page, I am including file with tables and screeshot of my problem. I was trying to use tabularx and longtables too, it did not help.

Thank you so so much for you help.
Adrian[image: Error]

Comment: Hello,  I am adding also a code of this table.

Comment: Did you forget the code you say you're adding? You cannot use `longtable` and `tabularx` together for the same table. However, there are packages which combine the facilities of both (at least 2 options, if I remember rightly).

Answer (score 1):

You have to put the table code in another file, like `table.tex` then you use it in the main code with `ltxtable` package, like this

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ltxtable}

\begin{document}

\LTXtable{\textwidth}{table.tex}

\end{document}
```

Your `table.tex` file can be just like this (with `tabularx` formatting)

```
\begin{longtable}{XXX}
\caption{...} %if needed
\label{...}\\ %if needed

... %the header in the first table page
\endfirsthead

... %the header in the other table pages
\endhead

... %the footer in the table pages (all but not last)
\endfoot

... %the footer in the last table pages
\endlastfoot

... %the table content
... %the table content
... %the table content

\end{longtable}
```